# Launcher gone after customizing it

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I did the upgrade on my laptop. GREAT!. Getting familiar with it and LOVING IT!.

(I switched to Ubuntu a month ago and NEVER looked back :)

Upgrade it my desktop, NOT so great! and I have NO clue how to fix it!

I was setting the launcher preferences like my laptop, changed the size of icons, auto hide format, launcher hid really well cause I can't find it anywhere!! Even the top R corner menu portion is gone off the top tool bar?? I can ONLY see 'File Edit GO Bookmarks Help' in top left & my background, NOTHING else : /
How can I fix this??

Comment: Please confirm that you have upgraded to 11.10?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the Unity plugin was disabled somehow. To fix it you need to restart the computer using the Unity 2D option.

If you hold down the power button on the computer until the dialogue box opens that gives you the option to choose restart and select it.

When the login screen appears you need to select Unity 2D by clicking on the little cog in the password entry box and select Unity 2D.

Once you have booted into the computer simply run Compiz Config Settings Manager *Dash ->Compiz* and ensure that you have a tick in the box next to the Unity Plugin

[image]